# How to center align a UILabel on top of an UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel

I have an UIImageView that has a UILabel on top of it. This UILabel has a text that shows a number to the user of how many people like his content ( kinda like the Facebook likes or comments ),
Both the UIImageView and the UILabel are small in size so the UI needs to be just perfect. Right now if the UILabel shows a 2 digits number it still shows up aligned properly but when I get into the 3 digits it kinds skews off, how can I make sure that I can always align it to the UIImageView via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Scott's answer, but with the code that the poster requested

```
//assume that UIImageView (imageView) and UILabel (label) are already defined
label.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y - label.frame.size.height, imageView.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Note: You'll also need to ensure that the struts and autoresize masks of the UILabel appropriately match that of the UIImageView to ensure this looks appropriately on screens of different sizes and different orientations.

Comment: this is good, but the problem is when I move up the number and reach 100, then the label moves to the right of the box.

Comment: Ok, please post a screenshot, it's hard to visualize what's happening

Comment: actually never mind, your got it, this code work perfectly. thanks bro,

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot of what's going on would be nice, but you can always try to make the label the same width as the image, and then center the text of the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.frame];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

This might work as UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated in iOS 6 and above.